# Object to org.w3c.dom.Element?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

In order to create a web service I got a number of XSD. There is a relation between them: one common schema forming a skeleton XML message while others serve for passing business information.
Then I have jaxb-converted all schemas to Java classes. 
And now I got a stuck: it is necessary to put given object, for example, an object of Person class into an element.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "any"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "MessagePrimaryContent")
public class MessagePrimaryContent {

    @XmlAnyElement
    protected Element any;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the any property.
     *
     * @return possible object is
     * {@link Element }
     */
    public Element getAny() {
        return any;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the any property.
     *
     * @param any allowed object is
     *            {@link Element }
     */
    public void setAny(Element any) {
        this.any = any;
    }

}
```

The Person class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "person", propOrder = {

    "firstName",
    "lastName"
})

    public class Person {


        protected String firstName;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String lastName;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the firstName property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setFirstName(String value) {
            this.firstName = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the secondName property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the lastName property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setLastName(String value) {
            this.lastName = value;
        }

    }
```

As I understand, I have to marshall it to a Document, from which I can get the Element(s). In order to do it I have written a special method. Unfortunately it was not successful so I think I do something wrong.
One of the version this method looks like that and it does not work properly.

```
public Element createPerson(RequestData requestData) throws Exception {

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

    Person person = new Person();

    person.setFirstName("Harry");
    person.setLastName("Kane");

    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(person, document);

    return document.getDocumentElement();}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "not successful". What exactly is the problem? Your code looks fine for me.

Comment: it returns "null" so the generated xml has not been inserted into necessary tag. Let us say, I am expecting <SenderRequest><Person ns1="someNamespace"><FirstName>Harry</FirstName><LastName>Kane</LastName><Person></SenderRequest>

Comment: but I really got <SenderRequest></SenderRequest>

Comment: Could you please post a MCVE of this?

Comment: Hmm..I've just revised my code a bit and tried to use a full name of a class at this line JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxb.example.Person.class) and it works!